# Prevent Pages from being loaded

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am developing my own kind of MVC style system for the webpages I create.  The file structure is as follows:

```
docs/contact/contact.php
img/
inc/
index.php
.htaccess
```

Inside Docs there are folders for each section of the website.  In this case I have expanded 'contact'.  The .htaccess file routes all URI's to index.php, but not if they are directly accessed i.e. domain.com/docs/contact/contact.php.

This is my .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=10

AddType "text/html; charset=UTF-8" html 
AddType "text/plain; charset=UTF-8" txt

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# if file not exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# if dir not exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# avoid 404s of missing assets in our script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(jpe?g|png|gif|css|js)$ [NC]

RewriteRule .* index.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

Is there a way to prevent people from accessing files inside the docs folder, unless it is directly called from the file index.php?  Can this be done with .htaccess?

Comment: Route ALL Requests to the index file and use an include over there to display subpages: `index.php?page=contacts` and in the source `include('docs/contact/contact.php')`

Answer (score 0):

You can define something in your index.php to prevent this:

```
define('MyAppLoaded', true);
```

And in your other files check with:

```
if (!defined('MyAppLoaded')) {
    // show message or handle direct access
}
```

But the real question is: Why are you putting all those files in your docroot if you don't want them to be directly accessible in the first place???

Imho the only php file in the docroot should be an index.php file with the following contents:

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap.php';
```

Comment: Sometimes I cannot access outside of public_html.  What can I do in that situation?

Comment: "What can I do in that situation?" I already answered that in my answer :P